# Find out if type is callable

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I need to figure out if template argument is a callable object with non-void return value.

I've defined the following:

```
template<class T, class U = T>
struct is_callable
{
    constexpr static const bool val = false;
};

template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::result_of_t<T()>>
{
    constexpr static const bool val = true;
};

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_func = is_callable<T>::val;
```

But the following variables all are `false`

```
auto lambda = []() {return 3.0; };

auto intIsFunc = is_func<int>; //false -- ok
auto functionIsFunc = is_func<std::function<int()>>; //false -- wrong
auto lambdaIsFunc = is_func<decltype(lambda)>; //false -- wrong
```

- What is wrong with the code?
- How to improve the is_func to return `true` not only on callable objects, but callable with return type which is constructible (use somewhere `std::is_constructible_v<>`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: 
Corrected. Don't want people to react on this small mistake instead of answering questions.

Comment: [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable), since C++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enable_if`

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_callable_non_void_return : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_callable_non_void_return<
    T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<void, std::result_of_t<T()>>>>
    : public std::true_type {};
```

This works because of SFINAE: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.

The compiler will see the second `is_callable_non_void_return` as a specialization of the first, and try to match the template by instantiating the `enable_if`: first `result_of_t`, then `is_same_v`. If **either** fails, then a substitution failure occurs and the compiler falls back to the general case.

Comment: I get an error with your code:

    n_void_return<enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type,void>'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=void
    1>        ]

Comment: The error was mangled. And I also fixed some errors in my answer.

Comment: This really is what I need. I still do not get why my version does not work?

Comment: I understand why this appears strange. Notice that in my code, the second `typename` is `void` both for the specialization (if there is no substitution failure) and for the base case. They are the same templates, but the specialization is more "specialized", so it is preferred. In your code, the specialization is considered only when T() returns a T.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what template specialization means.

```
template<class T, class U = T>
struct is_callable
```

this is the primary specialization.

When you do `is_callable<Foo>` it means you are typing `is_callable<Foo, Foo>`.  Nothing you co in other specializations can change this.

```
template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::result_of_t<T()>>
```

this attemptes to *match against* the arguments passed, it never changes them.

So for `is_callable<Foo>` this is `is_callable<Foo,Foo>`.  Matching `T` against `Foo` is easy; so now we have `T=Foo`.  We then look at the ones that are dependent on `T` -- `std::result_of_t<T()>` aka `std::result_of_t<Foo()>`.  This evaluates to the result of calling `Foo` with `()` (roughly).

If we had:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo operator(){ return {}; }
};
```

then `std::result_of_t<Foo()>` is `Foo`, and the specialization matches!

But if we have `Foo=std::function<void()>` then the result of `()` is `void` coming out of `std::result_of_t<Foo()>`.

Thus we have `is_callable<Foo, void>` matching against `is_callable<Foo, Foo>`.  This obviously doesn't match as `Foo` does not equal `void`.

---

```
template<class T, class U = void>
struct is_callable
// body unchanged
```

notice the `U=void` instead of the `U=T`.

```
template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::void_t<std::result_of_t<T()>>>
// body unchanged
```

and here we use `void_t`.

`std::void_t` takes any types passed to it and produces `void`.  Now let us go through the same exercise with `is_callable< std::function<int()> >`.

Under the primary specialization this becomes

```
is_callable<std::function<int()>, void>
```

we then try to match it against the specialization:

```
template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::void_t<std::result_of_t<T()>>>
```

again, `T=std::function<int()>` arrives immediately.  The second clause is in a dependent context, so we don't pattern match it.

```
struct is_callable<std::function<int()>, std::void_t<std::result_of_t<std::function<int()>()>>>

struct is_callable<std::function<int()>, std::void_t<int>>

struct is_callable<std::function<int()>, void>
```

and wow, this matches the types passed to the template!

`std::enable_if` uses a trick whereby if the first argument is `true`, it returns the second argument (defaulting to `void)`.  If the first argument is `false`, it is a substitution failure.

> How to improve the is_func to return true not only on callable objects, but callable with return type which is constructible (use somewhere `std::is_constructible_v<`

I'll skip the bodies:

```
template<class T, class=void>
struct is_callable
// ...
template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_constructible_v< std::result_of_t<T()> >
>>
```

now, for a type `T` for which `T()` is not constructible, the specialization fails to match because in computing the 2nd argument we get a substitution failure.  And when it is constructible, we get `void`.